# @JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSerializer.class is not working as expected

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an App Entity with some parameters like CustomerName , Address and CardNumber. While seriazlizing it with Jackson to a JSON, I want the card number to be masked. For example if the CardNumber is 12345678901234 I want the JSON to have the value as CardNumber : 1234******1234. So I added @JsonSerialize annotation on Card Number property and making it to use my custom serializer class. But this doesnt seems to be working.

Entity Class

```
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

  import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;

  @XmlRootElement
  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
  @XmlType(name = "TransactionDetailsType", propOrder = { "CustomerName", "Address", "CardNumber" })
  public class App {

      @XmlElement(name = "Address")
      private String address;

      @JsonSerialize(using = CardNumberMaskingSerializer.class)
      @XmlElement(name = "CardNumber")
      private String cardNumber;

      @XmlElement(name = "CustomerName")
      private String customerName;

      public String getAddress() {
          return address;
      }

      public String getCardNumber() {
          return cardNumber;
      }

      public String getCustomerName() {
          return customerName;
      }

      public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
      }

        public void setCardNumber(String cardNumber) {
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
       }

       public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
           this.customerName = customerName;
       }

   }
```

Custom Serializer Class

```
public class CardNumberMaskingSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

    private final static String MASK_CHAR = "*";

    @Override
    public void serialize(String cardNumber, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        String s = cardNumber.replaceAll("\\D", "");
        System.out.println(s);
        int start = 4;
        int end = s.length() - 4;
        String overlay = StringUtils.repeat(MASK_CHAR, end - start);
        String maskedNumber = StringUtils.overlay(s, overlay, start, end);
        System.out.println(maskedNumber);
        jgen.writeString(maskedNumber);
    }

}
```

Marshaller Class

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

 import org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream;
 import org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector;
 import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
 import org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector;

 public class AppMarshaller {

     private final ObjectMapper mapper;

     public AppMarshaller() {
         mapper = new ObjectMapper();

         AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();

              mapper.setDeserializationConfig(mapper.getDeserializationConfig().withAnnotation     Introspector(introspector));
         mapper.setSerializationConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig().withAnnotationIntr     ospector(introspector));
     }


public App read(String jsonText) {
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(jsonText, App.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


public String write(App details) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        mapper.setSerializationConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig().withAnnotationIntrospector(
                new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector()));

        mapper.writeValue(byteStream, details);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    try {
        return byteStream.toString("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

But when i tried to test it in JUNIT, by calling marshaller.write(app), the custom serializer is not getting called. So i am not getting the expected output. Can someone please help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue when I found that I am confusing myself with Jackson annotations and JAXB annotations. @XmlElement is jaxb and @JsonSerialize is jackson.

I wrote a custom jaxb marshaller amd resolved the issue.